# Running an executable, Terminal vs Clion Library not loaded

Tags: macos, c++11, clion, intel-mkl, macos-high-sierra

To give context (Unix MacOSX) I'm trying to link MKL with Eigen3. Everything works except for the fact that Clion can't run the executable that it builds, but I can manually run the Clion built exe in the terminal (./my_exe) (bash shell).

The error given is

> "dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libiomp5.dylib" 
>     Referenced from: /Users/MyUser/Desktop/ClionProjects/MyProject/cmake-build-debug/my_exe
>     Reason: image not found

I've tried setting the working directory to cmake-build-debug because that is where I am when manually running the exe through the terminal, no succes yet. I've checked the paths of the libraries and they seems fine (the ${DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH} does contain multiple paths, but one of them is the correct path, however if that was the issue why would it run fine in the terminal-shell?)

Additionally my unit tests support by BOOST won't run either.

Comment: The issue is solved!

Answer (score 1):

Issue is solved! How (someone, not me) fixed it. CLion DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH was not set (all other environment variables were). When looking at the configuration of your target you can look at the list of environment variables. ->Edit configurations, click the ... next to Environment variables, you can then add one by clicking the + and you can see the current set for your target build by clicking *show* for me the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH was not in this list, 
  so we manually added
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH : /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.1.126/mac/tbb/lib:/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.1.126/mac/compiler/lib:/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.1.126/mac/mkl/lib:/opt/local/lib:

To the executables environment variables when running the exe.