# CMake Error when compiling a project on Clion

Tags: cmake, g++, clion

I haven't been using Clion for some time and these days I tried to run an old project and it gave me this compile error (It used to work fine). Then I created a new project to test, the error still persists. I also tried to update my Clion. Here is the error message:

```
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/ninja/mac/ninja -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.2.0_1/bin/g++-9 -G Ninja /Users/yzr/Desktop/untitled
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 13.0.0.13000029
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.2.0_1/bin/g++-9
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.2.0_1/bin/g++-9 - broken
CMake Error at /Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:62 (message):
  The C++ compiler

    "/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.2.0_1/bin/g++-9"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /Users/yzr/Desktop/untitled/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
    
    Run Build Command(s):/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/ninja/mac/ninja cmTC_5a895 && [1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_5a895.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
    FAILED: CMakeFiles/cmTC_5a895.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o 
    /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.2.0_1/bin/g++-9    -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_5a895.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -c /Users/yzr/Desktop/untitled/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCXXCompiler.cxx
    dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/isl/lib/libisl.21.dylib
      Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.2.0_1/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/9.2.0/cc1plus
      Reason: image not found
    g++-9: internal compiler error: Abort trap: 6 signal terminated program cc1plus
    Please submit a full bug report,
    with preprocessed source if appropriate.
    See <https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues> for instructions.
    ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
    
    

  

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/yzr/Desktop/untitled/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/Users/yzr/Desktop/untitled/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Here is how my `CMakeList.txt` looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(untitled)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(untitled main.cpp)
```

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49342149/running-an-executable-terminal-vs-clion-library-not-loaded) and added the environment variable but it doesn't seem to work. This is really weird, as it all worked fine. It's just I didn't touch it for some time and need to take a look now. Has anyone encountered this before? Thanks!

Comment: Please, add the **error message** into the question post as a **text**, not as an *image*. Among other reasons, it is a requirement of Stack Overflow. See also [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Sorry, I just changed.

Comment: Have you checked [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59538261/dyld-library-not-loaded-usr-local-opt-isl-lib-libisl-21-dylib) about similar error message with `libisl` library?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to delete the previous generated cmake-build-debug directory. As the outside environment and version may be updated, some information generated in previous cmake-build-debug directory may no longer be useful. So delete it and Reload the make file to see whether the problem could be solved.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried what you suggested but it remains the same